# Is it possible to remove "throw IllegalArgumentException" from header here?

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I'm wondering if I can remove the IllegalArgumentException in the header of this method, have it in the body of the method, and still have it work the same way?

Thanks!

```
public Card(int value, String suit) throw IllegalArgumentException {
    LinkedList<String> suits = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"));//all suits in the lower case
    if(value >= 1 && value <= 13 && suits.contains(suit.toLowerCase())) {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal suit-value combination");//throw exception in case value or suit is wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `throws` instead of `throw` in the header

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Thanks, Snowy_1803.

Comment: @khelwood It still runs, but I don't know how to test it to see if it would hold up in different circumstances (which is why I wondering if it would just be the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to explicitly declare a `RuntimeException` in the method declaration. Since `IllegalArgumentException` is a `RuntimeException`, you can remove it.

From the [offical documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html):

> Runtime exceptions can occur anywhere in a program, and in a typical one they can be very numerous. Having to add runtime exceptions in every method declaration would reduce a program's clarity. Thus, the compiler does not require that you catch or specify runtime exceptions (although you can).

You can mention it tough in the JavaDoc section of the method. This give the consumer a hint about any unchecked exceptions thrown. It is also common to append this information indirectly to the parameters.

```
/**
  * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the suite combination is illegal
  */

/**
  * @param myParam the param, must not be null
  */
```

Parameter validation often includes throwning an `IllegalArgumentException` if one parameter does not meet the requirements. Since those are listed in the JavaDoc (here, *not null*) it is the programmers fault if he passes `null`.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help!